# how to use hook_forms()

Tags: forms

I'm trying to get multiple forms for a content type at one page

so, I went by hook_forms($form_id,$args), but when use it, I receive a not full populated form array

I have

**hook_menus()**

```
$items['user/%user/administracion/saldos-vacaciones-admin'] = array(
    'type'=>MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'title'=>'Saldos admin',
    'page callback'=>'pezgordo_saldos_dias_feriado_form',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('maneja personas'),
    'file' => 'saldos_dias_feriado_form.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'pezgordo').'/includes/user',
);
```

**includes/user/saldos_dias_feriado_form.inc**

```
function pezgordo_saldos_dias_feriado_form($persona=NULL){

$saldos = array_of_nodes();//this is the array of nodes I want their edit forms

$cuenta_forms = 0;
if($saldos){
    foreach($saldos as $ks=>$s){
        //$form_state[$ks]['build_info']['args'] = array($s);

        dpm("$cuenta_forms $ks");

        /*here! if I changes one statemet by the other, 
        I can see using A $form[$ks] is an array of 29 elements, 
        using B I get an aray of 53 elements, all node related items 
        are gone, so form doesn't show at all*/

        //A
        //$form[$ks] = drupal_get_form('saldo_dias_feriado_node_form-'.($cuenta_forms),$s);
        //B
        $form[$ks] = drupal_get_form('saldo_dias_feriado_node_form', $s);

        //dpm($form['$ks]);

        $cuenta_forms++;
    }//fin para cada saldo
}//fin hay saldos

return $form;

}
```

**pezgordo.module**

```
function pezgordo_forms($form_id, $args){
$forms = array();
// Check if the form id is of the pattern add_to_collection_form-[NUMBER]
if(preg_match('/^saldo_dias_feriado_node_form-\d+$/', $form_id)){
    $forms[$form_id]['callback'] = 'saldo_dias_feriado_node_form';
    //$forms[$form_id]['callback arguments'] = $args;
}
dpm($forms);
return $forms;
}
```

**please any help ? thanks**

Comment: This is still not working for me. Despite I can see every form has an unique identifier id, the submission of any form doesn't work. When I submit I receive a message: "El contenido de esta página ha sido modificado por otro usuario o usted ya ha enviado modif..."

Also, the field I changed at one form is updated (not in db, just in form) in all forms, not just the one I've changed

I can see a hidden field named "form_id", inside every form, the value of this field is the same on every form, HOW I CAN CHANGE THIS HIDDEN FIELD TO TRY IF THIS IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM ?? ... please ... help !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the forms with a unique ID each time. You can do this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($saldos as $ks=>$s){
  $form[$ks] = drupal_get_form('saldo_dias_feriado_node_form-' . $i, $s);
  $i++;
```

Comment: thank you @jaypan, I'm doing that. As I comment in my code, I'm calling drupal_get_form in two ways (A and B) alternatively . Using the A way, is resulting in a form array that **lacks of many node related items** (if not all). I've also tried passing $form_state as argument to hook_forms(), but no luck. Please, what else may I do to get this ?, thanks